# Our approach to a dynamic where clause in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, where-clause

We have a lot of queries in which we need to have the where clause behave dynamically, based on any amount of given filters. A filter is derived from user input (which is out of scope for this question).

We came up with the solution shown below:

---

A filter is represented in code by a list (plsql table) with zero or more elements, and a count variable which either contains the length of the list, or -1 if the list should be ignored (don't filter).

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_number_table AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

PROCEDURE get_filter(p_filter_type IN VARCHAR2,
                     p_key_list    OUT t_number_table,
                     p_count       OUT PLS_INTEGER) IS
BEGIN
  --normally, this procedure would consult the user input to find out what needs
  --to be filtered, but for this example just always return the same filters

  CASE p_filter_type
    WHEN 'ORDER' THEN
      p_key_list := t_number_table(11, 12, 13, 14);
      p_count    := 4; --user filtered on 4 orders
    WHEN 'PRODUCT' THEN
      p_key_list := NULL;
      p_count    := -1; --user did not filter on product
    WHEN 'CUSTOMER' THEN
      p_key_list := t_number_table(1000);
      p_count    := 1; --user filtered on 1 customer
  END CASE;
END;
```

This `get_filter` procedure returns the filter for when the user filters on four orders, does not filter on product and filters on exactly one customer.

If we want to obtain the set of orders that matches these filters, we use it as follows:

```
DECLARE
  v_order_list     t_number_table;
  v_order_count    PLS_INTEGER;

  v_product_list   t_number_table;
  v_product_count  PLS_INTEGER;

  v_customer_list  t_number_table;
  v_customer_count PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  get_filter('ORDER', v_order_list, v_order_count);
  get_filter('PRODUCT', v_product_list, v_product_count);
  get_filter('CUSTOMER', v_customer_list, v_customer_count);

  ...
  OPEN some_ref_cursor FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   order_header oh
    JOIN   order_line ol ON ol.orderno = oh.orderno
    WHERE  (v_order_count = -1 OR
              oh.orderno IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(v_order_list)))
    AND    (v_product_count = -1 OR
              ol.productno IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(v_product_list)))
    AND    (v_customer_count = -1 OR
              oh.customerno IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(v_customer_list)));
END;
```

What we like about our approach is that it's very flexible, and somewhat elegant. It also seems to perform ok, but I'm wondering how others approach this. Also, maybe there are some issues with our approach that we missed. What are the cons against this method?

Comment: I prefer to define a table or tables to contain the attribute-value mappings, then use a join or joins on the table(s) to produce the desired output. Advantages: 1) data-driven with little or nothing buried in code; 2) takes advantage of what relational databases do well (joining tables); 3) any changes are transactionalized; 4) not product specific. Disadvantages: 1) requires defining a table or tables to hold the data (trivial in most databases, although organizational requirements may make this difficult). IMO the advantages outweigh the disadvantages. YMMV. Share and enjoy

Comment: Another advantage to the Bob Jarvis solution is that you can create a tool that allows non-technical staff to control the queries.  This requires a well defined set of queries; I never feel confortable allowing non-techs to write free form queries.

Comment: On stackoverflow, you should ask specific questions to specific problems which ideally have a single correct answer.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I differ on `single correct answer`

Comment: This question would be perfect match to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/about !

Comment: @realspirituals: I said *ideally* a single correct answer. I don't mean that only one person is answering correctly, but ideally there is one truth about the question which is to be found. In contrast to "every answer is equally valid" (from the FAQ). http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask